# How to overcome Safari Mobile's 5 second timeout for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I have a bunch of javascript and jquery (1.6.1 - I know it is old) code that executes properly in Chrome & Firefox mobile, but in Safari it runs roughly 30% of the time.  I've tried wrapping the "troubled" function in a setTimeout, but that merely delays the execution of the function.  Is there a way to simply tell safari mobile to give the javascript more time to execute... you know like the 10 seconds firefox uses, or am I completely at the mercy of the browser and coding efficiency?

The situation I'm in is that I have a project where an engine builds a page, but it sucks and I have some post-page-build javascript that corrects most of the suckiness of the engine.  Unfortunately this correction takes just over 5 seconds on average and sometime safari just kills it and it doesn't happen.  I know the most correct solution is to modify the engine so that page construction doesn't have to happen client side, but I do not have access to update the engine.  I have already made some efficiency improvements but I'm running out of places to eek more out (currently looking at condensing) - it just takes a few seconds to do what I need to do.

What can I do to get just a little more time for safari to execute javascript?

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: A better question may be, 'how do I improve the performance of this script'? 5 seconds is a long time for JS execution to happen.

Comment: Do you know how it's timing the execution? For example, if you think it's eating up too much consecutive CPU time, you could try splitting the load (alas, for a longer period) by utilizing some `setTimeout` calls between expensive functions to give the browser time to breath -- But really, you shouldn't have JS execution take 5 seconds.

Comment: Use chrome profiling to know which part is the worst permormant

Comment: Will try profiling - thanks.